# Prevent unwanted pause() when appending a video element

Tags: javascript, cordova, html5-video

In a cordova project, i use the camera plugin. In browser, it creates a video element within a div with class `cordova-camera-capture`.

Due to the css framework I use (FrameWork7), this div is invisible and I'm unable to take the webcam picture.

So i decided to move the div in my view (in a div with ID `capture`).

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
      var element = e.target;

      if ( $(element).is('div.cordova-camera-capture') && !$(element).parent().is('div#capture') ) {
        $('#capture').append(element);
      }
    });
```

It works, but the video is stopped. I can see the webcam capture but on the console I encounter:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted
>   by a call to pause().

I can fix the fact the video is pause by relaunching it:

```
$('#capture').find('video').get(0).play();
```

But I don't find it a convenient way as it doesn't get rid off the primary error.

**Is there any way to prevent the pause() call on "moving" the div by appending it? Or any technique to move the element without triggering pause()?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `autoplay` attribute

```
<video autoplay>
```

Comment: I can't modify the video element itself. Since it comes from a plugin which can be modified by itself.